# Testing email markup against myself not working

Tags: google-schemas

I've used [this schema example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/hotel-reservation) and sent myself an email using the Email Markup App Script.

The mail is recieved but no Event card is shown. I've also validated it with the Google Markup Validator, and I'm not missing any required field. What am I doing wrong?

PD: Only "Action" markup worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

@whitenoisedb I see that you've tried sending the [lodgingreservation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/hotel-reservation) schema to yourself. If you're copying and pasting the example without modifying the *checkinDate* and *checkoutDate* attributes, your card will not generate until 2017.

*"checkinDate": "2017-04-11T16:00:00-08:00",
"checkoutDate": "2017-04-13T11:00:00-08:00"*

Use a current *checkinDate* (ex. *2015-12-15T16:00:00-08:00*) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are coming up soon and it is still not showing, there is a chance that this type of Google cards are not supported in your country